# Codeigniter Encryption Key

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption

Say I have this set up as my encryption key and I already have the encrypt library on autoload:

`$config['encryption_key'] = 'bjA{<ATCs1w5?,8N(bJvgO3CW_<]t?@o';`

How do I use it in an encrypt function?

```
function s()
{
    $something = $this->encrypt->encode('eoaighaeg',$key);
    echo $this->encrypt->decode($something, $key); 
}
```

^ Non working example to give you an idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to this documentation,
http://codeigniter.com/nightly_user_guide/libraries/encryption.html

If you didn't supply any key parameter for $this->encrypt->encode() function, it automatically use config encryption key.

```
$this->encrypt->encode($msg);
```

Comment: Please Change the Reference Document link, it's not working.

Answer (score 4):

You don't. CI already does that, as you can read on the [manual](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encryption.html)

If you want to pass a *custom* key, different from that one used in the config file, you need to specify it first:

```
$msg = 'Message';
$key = 'bjA{<ATCs1w5?,8N(bJv';

$encrypted_string = $this->encrypt->encode($msg, $key);
```

But that works only locally, otherwise you just use

```
$this->encrypt->encode($msg)
```

and CI applies the default one.

As with decoding it goes the same way, you don't specify the key if you use the default key, else pass your custom one as second parameter of `$this->encrypt->decode()`